# Django How to Register user in classes

Tags: django, class, view

I am currently using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4, I created the following site, which is a mock site to sign up for courses (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa9oD.jpg) where the titles are linked to another page like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND8YI.jpg), what I want to do is have the superuser be able to "register" in these classes through the button in page 2, any suggestions how to do it? Here is my code below, sorry for the wall of text:

Project Directory:

```
* cacademy:
    * __pycache__
    * __init__
    * settings
    * urls
    * wsgi
* Classes:
    * __pycache__
    * migrations
    * static
    * __init__
    * admin
    * models
    * tests
    * urls
    * views
* templates:
    * cacademy:
        * base.html
        * classes_list.html
        * courses_detail.html
*accounts:
    * __pycache__
    * migrations
    * __init__
    * admin
    * models
    * tests
    * urls
    * views
* db.sqlite3
* manage.py
```

My Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    teachername = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    teacherinfo = models.TextField()
    started_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Course
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def classes_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(started_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('started_date')
    return render(request, 'cacademy/classes_list.html', {'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'cacademy/courses_detail.html', {'course': course})
```

My cacademy\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from Classes import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^$', views.classes_list, name='classes_list'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/course/$', views.course_detail, name='course_detail'),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    ]
```

I know that I can use the ForeignKey for a OneToMany relationship, but I can't grasp the idea of how to input it into my code, I want the superuser to register in these courses above, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Models level You can use a `ManyToMany` relation for link users with courses, like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    teachername = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    teacherinfo = models.TextField()
    started_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', verbose_name='Students',
                                   related_name='courses', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then in your view in POST handler you can check `request.user.is_superuser` property, and if it's True, enroll Users to Courses by `course.users.add(user)`. You can find details on [Django documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com)

Comment: thanks for the info but every new "course" has automatically all the Users, how can i remove them?

Comment: @Sylas No, it isn't. Every new Course has no users when created, this is only database layer relation between two tables: Course and User. When you need to add user to course, you can use  `course.users.add(user)` and when you need to remove it -  `course.users.remove(user)`. After one of these operations you should do `course.save()`.